# DateTime.Parse() -- String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to consume an object returned by a third party .dll

```
public class AuroraTransaction
{
    ....
    public DateTime Date { get; }
    ....
}
```

I'm having trouble with that `Date` property:

```
// Gets a List from the third party .dll...
List<AuroraTransaction> transactions = report.RunReport();
```

Then:

```
foreach (AuroraTransaction trans in transactions)
{
    ....
    // This next line throws an error...
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(trans.Date.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    ....
}
```

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

If I put `trans.Date.ToString()` in the watch....

[image]

I'm stumped as to why I'm getting the error

Comment: You're using english US date time so what about `DateTime.Parse(trans.Date.ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US"));`

Comment: same result.  But I do appreciate the attempt!  I'm stumped.

Comment: @CodeNotFound "8/4/2017" is a valid date in the US and European formats,  One is August 4th and the other is April 8th.

Comment: I cant duplicate your error. Which line are you getting that error?

Comment: there seems to be something weird with `trans.Date`, which is an object that is returned from a third party .dll.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston What's the type of `trans` and more importantly the type of `trans.Date`?

Comment: This code works for me, so I don't know what your specific issue is then `DateTime.Parse("8/4/2017 7:38:29 AM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: I revamped the OP with better details

Comment: Why convert a `DateTime` to a `string` and then immediately back to a `DateTime`?  That makes no sense.  Why not just use `DateTime dt = trans.Date;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(trans.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  Odd... I thought I had tried this, but I guess not.  Much appreciated.

Comment: This code is redundant.  It doesn't make much sens to convert a `DateTime` to a `string` and back to a `DateTime`.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway This will truncate the milliseconds, if there were any.

Comment: try this `trans.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:ff") `

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure what you are trying to achieve here is not possible from what you are trying to do, like Mohammad Wasim said, it would be better to parse it then define the year, month, day, hour,minute,second.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(trans.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```